# Natural logarithm over natural logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How are you supposed to simplify a natural log over another natural log?

Ex.

$$\frac{\ln(64)}{\ln(4)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

One logarithm divided by the other is equivalent to a change of base of the logarithm:

$$\ln(a)\div\ln(b) = \log_b(a)$$

Do you know what $\log_4(64)$ is?

Comment: Yeah its 3, since 4^3 = 64

Comment: Oh, so we can use the change of base rule to get one log and then get the answer from that.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\frac{\ln (64)}{\ln (4)}=\frac{\ln (4^3)}{\ln (4)}
\end{align}

Note that $\log a^b= b \log a$